# To default to the first record returned from the ReferenceInput in SelectInput

Tags: react-admin

Please how can I initialize the selectinput to the first record returned by the ReferenceInput?

For example, person resource returns this

```
persons: [
  {"id":1,"name":"John"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Peter"},
  {"id":3,"name":"Paul"}
]
```

I want the selectinput to default to **John** being the first record from the persons resource

I saw a similar post where someone said one can use **defaultValue** property of the SelectInput, but it did not work for me.

Thanks

See the code below:

```
<ReferenceInput
  label="RDM/WDM"
  source="salesmgr"
  reference="persons"
  sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }}                   
>
    <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

Comment: Striped, please do you have a solution for this. I thought Miguel's answer was correct at first but I have just tested now and it is not. Thanks

Comment: It seems you can't "populate" children choices of ReferenceInputs like `AutocompleteArrayInput` or `SelectInput`. I think the only way to archived it is to write a very custom components fetching the data and displaying it with its own logic out of the `ReferenceInput`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the defaultValue property to ReferenceInput as follow:

```
<ReferenceInput
  label="RDM/WDM"
  source="salesmgr"
  reference="persons"
  sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }}
  defaultValue={1}             
>
   <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

Comment: Sorry this was not solved. I still need assistance here. Miguel's solution defaults to the id that has 1. When the ReferenceInput is rendering its record, there is no way to know the value of the id at runtime.

Comment: Hi Miguel, sorry this was not solved. Your solution assumes that the record being returned will have id=1 but there is not way to know the values of the id at runtime from the referenceinput